# TypeScript: Getting the type of the property at keyof T

Tags: typescript, generics, types, syntactic-sugar

I'm having a bit of fun by playing with TypeScript and its typing system - it's nothing critical, but maybe some of you find this as interesting or fun as me.

Since I often find myself sorting arrays by properties of said objects, I thought to myself, "why not implement a sortBy function?".

```js
Array.prototype.sortBy = function <T, P extends keyof T>(
  this: T[],
  compareFn: (a: unknown, b: unknown) => number,
  key: P
): T[] {
  return this.sort((a, b) => compareFn(a[key], b[key]));
};
```

Usage:

```js
interface A {
  keyA: string;
  keyB: number;
}
const arr: A[] = [
  { keyA: "a", keyB: 42 },
  { keyA: "b", keyB: 1337 },
  { keyA: "c", keyB: -1 },
];
arr.sortBy((a: number, b: number) => b - a, "keyB");
```

The implementation works, and I think it's cool that this is even possible to have the list of keys as a type variable - as far as I know this behavior isn't possible in C# for example.

There's just one last thing I'd like to clean up - those being the `unknown` types for the comparator. The compiler can't catch any errors ahead of runtime here which can be dangerous. Is it possible to tell TS "the type that the property P in T has"?

I imagine something like `K extends typeof P in T` or `K extends typeof T[P]`.

If this is possible, I would be able to even add sub-keys to the function declaration to search by properties deeper inside the object tree.

PS: I know this is a pretty contrived problem, and I don't think that `K extends typeof T[P]` would be useful for many situations at all. But playing with code and having a discussion about it is great fun and deepens the understanding for the language in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you should have to do is reference the key value: `T[P]` see:

```js
Array.prototype.sortBy = function <T, P extends keyof T>(
  this: T[],
  compareFn: (a: T[P], b: T[P]) => number,
  key: P
): T[] {
  return this.sort((a, b) => compareFn(a[key], b[key]));
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLRnvw)

Comment: Wow I didn't expect this to be possible! Thank you very much! So I was on the right track - I just didn't expect I didn't have to create another generic type variable ^^